# I want to compile C file

Tags: compiling, c, g++, compiler

I want to compile c file. I use `g++ <filename> -o <output-filename>`

Error: `ch34x.c:13:24: fatal error: linux/init.h: Directory or file doesnt exist.
(here is hash I cant type here)include <linux/init.h>`

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: This looks like you are missing the linux/init.h module (which is highly unlikely) or that gcc does not know where to look for this module. I have found this file in my machine in this path: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-56/include/linux

Comment: `apt-file` helps a lot to identify the packages that provide missing headers: `apt-file search linux/init.h`

Comment: @mastov linux/init.h I have in PC.

Comment: use the command `gcc` g++ is for c++, gcc compiles c.

Comment: @j0h Same error.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/linux-module-h-915605/) looks like the thing you need.

Make sure you have `linux-headers-generic` installed.